# Run long process continously using Tkinter (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, multiprocessing

After some time trying to figure out how the Tkinter library works I have run into a problem. The script i wrote uses multiprocessing, and because the script needs to be as fast as possible I minimized the amount of traffic between the processes. This means that it takes about a minute to complete an enormous amount of tasks.

(If this task gets aborted halfway through, the used files will get corrupted).

The problem is that i want a stop button in my GUI to stop the script the proper way. After some research i haven't made any progress in finding a solution, so maybe some of you could help. I basically need a way to tell the script halfway through a task that it has to stop, after which the script will continue until the task is finished.

Edit:
The way my script is set up:

(This is missing the Tkinter part, because i don't know the solution to it yet).

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def Setup():
    #defines all paths of the files that are edited (and a whole lot more)

def Calculation(x, y, Primes):
    #takes an x and y value, calculates the value of that coordinate and determines
    #if the value is prime. Returns True of False, and the calculated value.

def Quadrant(List):
    #takes a huge list of coordinates that have to be calculated. These
    #coordinates (x and y) are passed to the 'Calculation' function, one by one.

    #Returns all the calculated coordinates and if they are prime or not (boolean)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Filenames = Setup()
    Process = Pool(4)

    while True:
        #Loop the main bit of the code to keep expanding the generated image
        Input = [List of all coordinates, split into 4 quadrants (seperate lists) evenly]
        Output = Process.map(Quadrant, Input)

        #Combine all data and update list of primes

        #Detects if escape is pressed, stops if true.
```

I am basically looking for a way to stop the while loop above, or an alternative to this loop.

Comment: Are you using the `multiprocessing` module? Or are you referring to `multiprocessing` in a generic manner? If you're using the `multiprocessing` module, then you can install a signal handler on that.

Comment: if it is an issue about the files getting corrupted you may consider making a temporary file and changing its name when the process was successful.  But to provide any real solution I'd need to know basically how your program is setup. (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: I just pass a manager dictionary to each process and test for dict["process-1"]=True. or whatever.  Then set it to False to abort a process.  And you should clarify --> "a way to tell the script halfway through a task that it has __to stop__, after which the script __will continue__ until the task is finished."

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yes, i am using the multiprocessing module.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen McDonald-Jensen, i added a simplified version of my script

Comment: @CurlyJoe Joe, I basically meant that the task has to stop, without aborting it suddenly. The script has to wait untill it's task is finished, and then look if a button is pressed to decide if it has to continue or not.

Comment: Possible solution with tkinter: display a window in main window, showing progress and containing a stop button.  Replace while loop with root.after calls (search SO for '[tkinter] root.after' for examples.  The command function would `root.after_cancel(current_after_callback)` and then wait for current tasks to complete.  If you use Process.start, that would be Process.join.  I am now sure what you do for Pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I basically meant that the task has to stop, without aborting it suddenly. The script has to wait untill it's task is finished, and then look if a button is pressed to decide if it has to continue or not*

We have no code from you to respond to, so if you are using a while() (note that you can also just issue a return from the function if some condition is True/False).

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def test_f(test_d):
   """  frist process to run
        exit this process when dictionary's 'QUIT' == True
   """
   while not test_d["QUIT"]:
      print "     test_f", test_d["QUIT"]
      time.sleep(1.0)

def test_f2(name):
    """ second process to run.  Runs until the for loop exits
   """
    for j in range(0, 10):
       print name, j
       time.sleep(0.5)

    print "second process finished"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   ##--- create a dictionary via Manager
   manager = Manager()
   test_d = manager.dict()
   test_d["QUIT"] = False

   ##---  start first process and send dictionary
   p = Process(target=test_f, args=(test_d,))
   p.start()

   ##--- start second process
   p2 = Process(target=test_f2, args=('P2',))
   p2.start()

   ##--- sleep 2 seconds and then change dictionary
   ##     to exit first process
   time.sleep(2.0)
   print "\nterminate first process"
   test_d["QUIT"] = True
   print "test_d changed"
   print "data from first process", test_d

   ##---  may not be necessary, but I always terminate to be sure
   time.sleep(5.0)
   p.terminate()
   p2.terminate()

   """ Thanks Doug Hellmann
       Note: It is important to join() the process after terminating it.
       in order to give the background machinery time to update the.
       status of the object to reflect the termination
   """
   p.join()
   p2.join()
```

Comment: Thanks! this was basically what i was looking for :)