# Run function while Checkbutton is checked (Tkinter, Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, checkbox, tkinter

This question is a follow up to:
[Run long process continously using Tkinter (Python 2.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899279/run-long-process-continously-using-tkinter-python-2-7?noredirect=1#comment59477396_35899279)
In the previous topic i asked about running a funtion continuously until a button is pressed. This funtion takes a long time to complete, and basically i wanted to stop the process (don't repeat the function) if a button was pressed.
I got an answer to my question, but i was wondering if this is possible using the Checkbutton function.

I know i can call a function using the Checkbutton (using command=[funtionname]), but what i need is a way to call a function continuously while the Checkbutton is checked, and stop when it's unchecked. Is this possible using tkinter?

Thanks in advance for any answers,
Harm

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the process is a repeated process. You can just check the `state` of the button at every repeat with `var.get()` (assuming that the `var` is the variable of the `checkbutton`) and `break` out of the function if it is unchecked.

This is not a really elegant solution, and if a repeat takes a long time, the last "round" will still finish after the uncheck, so it is not immediate.